# Best Practice for AWS IAM access keys for use with AWS SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, sdk

I want to know the best practice used by big company's for programmatic access for multiple AWS services as there are multiple programs needing access to different-2 services so how it is managed? Did they create multiple access keys for each program for different-2 services or create single one having access to all services?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. What is accessing AWS? Are these servers in an on-premise data center? Are they EC2 servers? AWS services? Azure? This makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: These are Ec2-servers and accessing different-2 s3 buckets and other services such as SNS, SQS.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice for AWS resources such as EC2 / Lambda / etc is to use IAM roles, detailed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html). In short you don't create a user for a server, you create a role that the service can assume that has a set of permissions which is associated with the EC2 server.

That server with a role is given "temporary" credentials when it's running so it can access any service that the IAM role permits. When I say "temporary", the credentials give to the service are short lived, maybe 24 hours, but when they expire new credentials are issued. This is usually transparent, unless you're writing software that uses them, in which case you have to check them occasionally. I might not have the fine details quite right there, but it's more or less correct.

AWS has predefined policies which can make defining roles easier.

For example, you can define role that says "EC2 servers with this role can push to SQS, pull from SQS, execute this one lambda function" and anything not explicitly granted is denied. Sometimes it takes a bit of experimenting to get the permissions you need worked out. Least privilege is best so that if a resource like EC2 server is compromised it doesn't have admin rights to AWS and can't delete everything or say start crypto mining.

If you're working in a large company doing AWS work I suggest you get some AWS training. Online training for AWS Architect Associate with a place like Cloud Guru is a minimum you'd need. AWS is complex. I've been working in AWS full time for years, but I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need predefined access policies to resources (like SQS,EC2,ElastiCache etc). After that you can add user with programmatic access and store credential in safe way or use Roles to assign it to services for access. For example: create IAM role to access RDS and assign it to ec2 instance, then try to access our database from ec2 instance.